# pkill -n java works at console but not in a script

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to write a script that runs a java program "Loop", and then after 5 seconds, terminates that java program, however, it's not terminating the program when I use the "pkill" option, I'm sorry for asking such a basic question, and I have looked around the internet, but I can't find a solution. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
javac Loop.java
java Loop
sleep 5
pkill -n java
```

When I run the command pkill -n java from the terminal, as opposed to in a script, it does as I expected, why is this?

Comment: Please try to use a title that distinguishes your question from other questions about bash.

Answer (score 2):

Your bash script is waiting for `java` to complete so you'll need to run it as a background process which will start your Loop code and then return immediately, allowing the rest of your script to run:

```
java Loop &
```

More information: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html

Comment: A fine answer -- only quibble I have is with the suggested reference. The ABS doesn't give much attention to showcasing good practices in its examples, making it often a poor choice for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Since you run `java Loop` in foreground, the next line `sleep 5` doesn't get executed until your JVM exits (which is probably never, if `Loop` is actually an infinite loop).

So you need to start that in background:

```
java Loop &
```

Also, for killing that specific background job (rather than killing the newest JVM), you can do:

```
kill $!
```

Comment: what does $! do? How does it find the PID of Loop?

Comment: It's a bash special parameter that "expands to the process ID of the most recently executed background (asynchronous) command": http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters

Comment: `$!` returns the pid of the last executed command, which in this case would be the java call.

Comment: why is the dollar sign required as well, surely you'd only need the "!" parameter, as that "Expands to the process ID of the most recently executed background (asynchronous) command."